# sharekit doesn't let me set custom facebook messages when sharing

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

When I share an image via Facebook using the latest version of the sharekit library, it sets the pre-filled status default message as the message, but doesn't give the user the opportunity to change that message like you can when sharing using sharekit on Twitter.  Is this possible with Facebook using ShareKit?

Comment: Where you able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get around getting the text from the user if that's what you want. Otherwise you could pre-define a set of standard text's youself.

Changing the default share text inside `ShareKit` is very simple:

```
NSString *someText = @"This is a blurb of text I highlighted from a document.";
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:someText];
```

[The documentation](http://getsharekit.com/docs/#text) shows some more ways on how to use `ShareKit` at its best.

*Yes, it is possible to use ShareKit with facebook have a look at the `SHKConfig.h` file.*

Comment: > You won't get around getting the text from the user if that's what you want. << i don't understand this sentence.  I'm trying to allow the user to change or add text to the default message the same way Twitter works on ShareKit

Comment: I was just pointing out that you could either set a default message youself or have the user type in something.

Comment: i explicitly stated in my question that I can set the prefilled default status message; and that that doesn't give the user the opportunity to type in something.  Twitter does....